# Buddypress: Default sort oder for Group Directory

Tags: php, wordpress, directory, buddypress

I want the groups in the group-directory to be sorted alphabetically in Buddypress, unless the user picks his own sorting via dropdown.

I tried via custom functions:

```
add_filter('bp_after_has_groups_parse_args', function ($options) 
{
    if (bp_is_groups_directory()) {
        if(!$options['type']) 
            $options['type'] = 'alphabetical';
        
    }
    return $options;
});
```

As per documentation, $options[‘type’] is “null” when the user has NOT yet picked an option in the dropdown, i.e. when it’s the initial sorting.

At least it says it in line 995:
https://github.com/buddypress/BuddyPress/blob/master/src/bp-groups/classes/class-bp-groups-group.php#L995

But it does not seem to work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try deleting this ` if(!$options['type']) `

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it makes sense because than the drop-down sorting is not possible anymore at all. I just wanna set the initial default sorting

Comment: @shanebp: Or what do you think? Isnt it, that when I remove like you said, that it's forced globally?

Comment: If not set by a user, `type` is set to `active`. It is never `null`.  I don't know how to avoid that with a filter.  Try this approach, adjusting for using the nouveau templates. https://www.green-box.co.uk/buddypress-sort-groups-page-alphabetically-default/

Comment: @shanebp I found yet another solution, unfortunately it required modifying the core files... Because the templates are not properly separated in the buddyboss. (Im using buddyboss). Modifying `bp_nouveau_get_groups_filters` and just moving the alphabetic option to the top -> this way it is selected in case the user has not yet picked another ordering :)

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Perhaps you could edit your answer to show the approach you used.

Comment: @shanebp: Do you know, is there an easy way to disable saving the sorting in the user cookie / session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In buddy press 10.0.0, you just need to change the bp-groups-template.php in the following location:

/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-groups/bp-groups-template.php

In the file, find this area:

/**

- Start the Groups Template Loop.

In the function bp_has_groups, find this section:

```
$r = bp_parse_args(
    $args,
    array(
        'type'               => $type,
        'order'              => 'ASC',   // changed from DESC 
        'orderby'            => 'name',  // changed from last_activity
```

I added the info after the // so I know what changes were made from the original.

This sets the default first viewing of the Groups page to an Alphabetical listing.  We are implementing Youzify over top of BuddyPress, so I also changed the default Order By listing in

/wp-content/plugins/youzify/includes/public/templates/groups/index.php

/**
* Fires inside the groups directory group types.
*
* @since 1.2.0
*/
do_action( 'bp_groups_directory_group_types' ); ?>

```
            <li id="groups-order-select" class="last filter">

                <label for="groups-order-by"><?php _e( 'Order By:', 'youzify' ); ?></label>

                <select id="groups-order-by">
                    <option value="alphabetical"><?php _e( 'Alphabetical', 'youzify' ); ?></option>
                    <option value="active"><?php _e( 'Last Active', 'youzify' ); ?></option>
                    <option value="popular"><?php _e( 'Most Members', 'youzify' ); ?></option>
                    <option value="newest"><?php _e( 'Newly Created', 'youzify' ); ?></option>

                    <?php

                    /**
                     * Fires inside the groups directory group order options.
                     *
                     * @since 1.2.0
                     */
                    do_action( 'bp_groups_directory_order_options' ); ?>
                </select>
```

Only change here from the original was to take this line:

```
                    <option value="alphabetical"><?php _e( 'Alphabetical', 'youzify' ); ?></option>
```

from the bottom of the list, to the top.

Hope this helps anyone down the road.